# Is it possible to export a graph from Gephi to orientDB ?

Tags: graph, orientdb, gephi

I'm new to gephi and orientdb and I would like some advice about the below task.

Currently there is a way to stream the orientDB graph into Gephi (using a plugin) but is there a way by which I can export a graph ( created via Gephi or by importing a CSV file into gephi) to orientDB ?

#### My environment:

```
Version used: Gephi 0.9.2
Java version: 8_151
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
orientdb: 2.2.29 community version
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I have found no way to import the graph from Gephi to orientDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way is to use spreadsheet export and then import the CSV, here the [doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Import-from-CSV-to-a-Graph.html)

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. Thanks!